# Async await Chain Responsibility Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Hello i am having an issue using async and await in a Chain Responsibility Pattern, when the HandlerRequest is executed and an await operation is hitting another task is fire not waiting the first task to finish, so the first task doesn't finish and the second task finish exiting the method, leaving the first task uncompleted

**Calling a queue of operations to execute**

```
private async Task DoOperations(CancellationToken token)
{
    foreach (var operation in _operationDetails)
    {
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        await h1.HandleRequest(operation.OperationTask);
    }
}
```

**Handler**

```
public abstract class Handler
{
    protected Handler successor;
    
    public void SetSuccessor(Handler successor)
    {
        this.successor = successor;
    }
    
    public abstract Task HandleRequest(OperationDetails.OPERATIONS operation);
}
```

**Portion of code Handler h1**

```
public override async Task HandleRequest(OperationDetails.OPERATIONS operation)
{
    if (operation == OperationDetails.OPERATIONS.SERVER_GET_AUDIO_LIST)
    {
        _updateLabelMessage?.Invoke(this, "Obteniendo lista de audios del servidor.");
        var result = await _services.AudioService.DownloadAudioListServerAsync(_token);
        _raiseRichTextInsertMessage?.Invoke(this, (result.status, result.statusMessage));
        if (result.status)
        {
            _getAudioListFiles?.Invoke(this, result.data);
        }
    }
    else if (successor != null)
    {
        successor.HandleRequest(operation);
    }
}
```

**Portion of code Handler h3**

```
public override async Task HandleRequest(OperationDetails.OPERATIONS operation)
{
    if (operation == OperationDetails.OPERATIONS.SERVER_DELETE_AUDIO)
    {
        _updateLabelMessage?.Invoke(this, "Eliminando audios del servidor");
        foreach (AudioFile file in _audioFileListToDelete)
        {
            _updateLabelMessage?.Invoke(this, "Eliminando audio: " + file.name);
            var result = await _services.AudioService.DeleteAudioServer(file.name, _token);
            _raiseRichTextInsertMessage?.Invoke(this, (result.status, result.statusMessage));
            if (_token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _raiseRichTextInsertMessage?.Invoke(this, (false, "Operacion Cancelada."));
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (successor != null)
    {
        successor.HandleRequest(operation);
    }
}
```

The first operation called is h3 but when this line of code is executed

```
var result = await _services.AudioService.DeleteAudioServer(file.name, _token);
```

The next handler (h1) is called not processing all the files in **_audioFileListToDelete**

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `Invoke`, and you shouldn't be mixing service calls with UI updates either. As to your actual problem, show something that actually compiles and exhibits your issue, this is way too much unrelated, uncompilable code you're throwing at us.

Comment: I don't really see the point of your pattern. If you want run some sequence of operations based on user input, why not just map the enum to classes or delegates and run them in a loop?

Comment: TBH looks very strange. Can you post a [mre] somewhere?